# use while loop for change after every click in jquery

Tags: jquery, loops, while-loop

I want change somethings after click events, but I need use while loop for make short code.

for example:

```
$('#DIV1').click(function() {
  // DoSomething     
}
$('#DIV2').click(function() {
  // DoSomething
}
```

use while loop for that

```
var i = 1; var ExapmleVar
while(i < 5)
{
 $('#DIV' + i).click(function() {
  ExapmleVar = i; 
 }
}
```

in the result ExapmleVar = 6 it's not true for me i want ExampleVar equal to 1 in first loop and equal to 2 in second loop and etc

Comment: While is not your solution. State you exact problem, otherwise in my experience  the question is good candidate for [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create event using fix prefix operator . here div[id^=DIV] assign click event to add div element which have id with prefix 'DIV'. $(this).index() return index of that element in a group of divs whit id is stat with 'DIV'

```
 $('div[id^=DIV]').click(function() {
  // DoSomething  
   ExapmleVar = ($(this).index() + 1);   
 }
```

Comment: It will not work in case if any other element is present in between `$('div[id^=DIV]')`

Comment: please explain a little, I want use it for id(s) 
can i write like this: $('#divid[id^=divid])?

Comment: @MojtabaSh  $('div[id^=DIV]')  .. div is element and  DIV as per your example prefix for each div id like DIV1, DIV2 DIV3 .  so this $('div[id^=DIV]')  assing event to all divs which have id started with DIV.

Comment: @MojtabaSh  check my updated answer . i have added some explanations regarding  $('div[id^=DIV]')

Answer (score 0):

use `id starting with` selector

```
$('div[id^=DIV]').click(function() {
```

[**Documentation here**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

or

```
   $('className').click(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Looping is bad practice in that case, You can use class instead like,

```
$('.common-class').click(function(){
   ExapmleVar = $('.common-class').index(this)+1;
});
```

```js
$('.common-class').click(function(){
   alert($('.common-class').index(this)+1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="common-class">1</div>
<div class="common-class">2</div>
<div class="common-class">3</div>
<div class="">Not common. Yeah!</div>
<div class="common-class">4</div>
```